# I need to compare two variables/interfaces and it is not working

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
IPv4=$( ifconfig |grep -v 'eth1:' |grep -A 1 'eth1'| tail -1 |cut -d ':' -f 2 |cut -d ' ' -f 1)
IPnode1=$"111.22.333.44"
IPnode2=$"111.22.333.45"


ifconfig |grep -v 'eth1:' |grep -A 1 'eth1'| tail -1 |cut -d ':' -f 2 |cut -d ' ' -f 1

if [[ "$IPv4" = "$IPnode1" ]]; then

   echo "found the address "
   echo "111.22.333.44   VM01.com VM01" >> /etc/hosts

else

   echo "The address does not match"

fi

  ifconfig |grep -v 'eth1:' |grep -A 1 'eth1'| tail -1 |cut -d ':' -f 2 |cut -d ' ' -f 1

if [[ "$IPv4" = "$IPnode2" ]]; then


      echo ""
      echo "found the address "
      echo "111.22.333.45   VM02.com VM02" >> /etc/hosts

else

   echo "The address does not match"

fi
```

Comment: What's in $IPv4 after executing the first line?

Comment: BTW, `ifconfig` on Linux is deprecated and has been unmaintained (except by distros adding their own local patches) for over a decade; it's completely unaware of modern Linux networking features (like named aliases), and consequently can misrepresent advanced configurations' status. New code should use the `ip` tool from `iproute2` instead; this also gives you a single-line-per-interface output option so you don't need hackery equivalent to the `grep -A 1 | tail` done here.

Comment: More to-the-point, `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x yourscript` will log each line as it's run, making it easier to follow what's going on with logic errors. (One caveat is that when running as root, modern versions of bash don't allow `PS4` to be inherited via the environment for security reasons, so you need to put that assignment in your code to get the logs to include line number).

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always report "The address does not match". If the address matches `$IPnode1`, then it doesn't match `$IPnode2`, and vice versa. You should only execute the second test when the first one fails.

```
if [[ "$IPv4" = "$IPnode1" ]]; then
    echo "found the address "
    echo "$IPnode1   VM01.com VM01" >> /etc/hosts
elif [[ "$IPv4" = "$IPnode2" ]]; then
    echo "found the address "
    echo "$IPnode2   VM02.com VM02" >> /etc/hosts
else
    echo "The address does not match"
fi
```

Comment: How you think I should re-write this ?

Comment: You are correct about the result I am getting "The address does not match".

Comment: I think it should work the way I rewrote it. What does `echo $IPv4` show?

Comment: echo "$IPnode1   VM02.com VM02" >> /etc/hosts please let me know if ($IPnode1) is correct or should that be ($IPnode2) ?

Comment: That was a typo. You could also use `$IPv4` in both places.

Comment: This is a cluster system I need to catch the active interface when and add the entry in the /etc/hosts ....

Comment: What's the problem? If the active interface address is `$IPnode1` it will add the `VM01` line, if the active interface address is `$IPnode2` it will add the `VM02` line.

Comment: I just tested that it does not add the $IPnode2 when it is on VM02

Comment: it still add the VM01 info

Comment: Can you add the complete output of `ifconfig` on VM02?

Comment: The best way to debug a shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning. It will then show every line as it's being executed, with the variables expanded.

Comment: $IPV4 gets the correct interface according to the VM it is pointing to .

Comment: it does get me the correct interface of $IPnode2 if I run the ifconfig COMMAND

Comment: so what I am trying to do is when I am on VM01 and the ifconfig got the correct interface it will add the entry in /etc/hosts ..So this is a cluster primary / Failover so when the failover becomes the primary it will be VM02 and that needs to be in the /etc/hosts

Comment: I don't really understand. Is the address of `eth1` changing when failover happens? Do you re-run the script when that happens?

Comment: Why don't you just put both `VM01` and `VM02` in `/etc/hosts` all the time.